# How to copy content from one file to many files using threads

Tags: c++, boost

I have one big file. It is a text file so I am reading one line at a time.

```
std::ifstream inFile(  "big_file.txt" );
std::string line;
while( getline( inFile, line ) )
{

}
```

I want to distribute the lines that I read from 'big_file.txt' to several files. The file count depends on the number of cores available on the machine.
***Edit:*** The target files might be on different physical devices, or content possibly sent to a different machine 
 
My (unsuccesful)attempt so far is as follows

```
// list of writer objects each running in its own thread
std::vector<FileWriter> writers;    
// create as many threads as there are cores
unsigned long const cores = boost::thread::hardware_concurrency();
for( unsigned long i = 0; i < cores; ++i)
{
    std::ostringstream ss; 
    ss << i; 
    FileWriter rt(ss.str());
    writers.push_back(rt);
}
```

then as I call `getline(inFile, line),` I want to be able to send the line to the threads in a round-robin fashion. It really does not have to be in round-robin; whatever method is best to distribute the work among threads is fine.
I have run out of ideas.
Please suggest boost and pre c++11 STL as I don't have a complete c++11 environment yet.

Comment: You'll probably find that multithreading is not going to help much for speeds - hitting disk is one of the slowest operations on a PC. Once you've swamped the drive i/o channels, more threads aren't going to help and just slow things down.

Comment: I'd think there would be a little gain due to buffering... but you'd need to ensure threads are at least synced to read from same point in file. Having said that, you can just let a single thread do one async double-buffered read and 4 async writes.

Comment: @user1240436 Reading is done by a single thread, the main thread. Only writing is multi-threaded

Answer (score 1):

Unless each new file is on a separate physical device, it is unlikely that there would be a performance gain simply by using multiple threads to write the individual files.  This type of process will be I/O bound rather than CPU bound typically.

One important thing to make sure of is to use buffered I/O (which it appears to be the case since you show `ifstream`).  Without buffered I/O, the latency of writing individual lines to different files would be a huge bottleneck.

**Edit** Given that the individual lines may be written to separate devices, then it *might* gain in performance by using multiple threads.  If there is a long latency (e.g., on a network send call if sending to another machine via some mechanism), then other threads could still be writing to other locations, so that would definitely help.

I might not completely understand the question, but it seems then it would just make sense to use a [thread pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern).  One possibility would be to use [threadpool](http://threadpool.sourceforge.net/). I have not used it, but it seems to have a good reputation.

Comment: The target files may be on different physical devices. Just edited my question to make this clear.